# How to change IP and PORT of Java Database Connection class dynamically?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, database-connection

I have created a Java **class** for **connecting to the MySQL database** for my Java SWING Application.

```
public class DB1 {

private static Connection c;

public static Connection getMyConnection() throws Exception {
    if (c == null) {
        JTextField myUserNameTextField = new JTextField();
        JTextField myPasswordTextField = new JTextField();
        JTextField myIPTextField = new JTextField();
        JTextField myPortTextField = new JTextField();
        String myUserName = myUserNameTextField.getText();
        String myPassword = myPasswordTextField.getText();
        String myURL = "jdbc:mysql:// " + myIPTextField.getText() + ":" + myPortTextField.getText() + "/DBName";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        c = DriverManager.getConnection(myURL, myUserName, myPassword);
    }
    return c;

}

public static void InsertEditDelete(String sql) throws Exception {
    getMyConnection().createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
}

public static ResultSet Search(String sql) throws Exception {
    return getMyConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
}
}
```

I want to **dynamically change the IP** , which is localhost here **and the port number from Jtextfields** , so u do not recompile every time u **change** the IP and PORT number. These JTextfields should get **opened up in a JFRAME**

Comment: I created my class according what you told me. Now how do I get to display Jtextfields to enter the details. These details should also get saved in the class.

Comment: one time you are saying you want to take hostname and port from textfield and another time you are saying you want to access from table... please clear question... re-iterate your question again....

Comment: Sorry, I just want to change it using JTextFields. I want these textfields to open in a frame.

Comment: see my updated answer `Update 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT username, password, host, port FROM  myAllData where id=1");

String myURL = "jdbc:mysql:// " + rs.getString("host") + ":" + rs.getString("port") + "/DBName"
String myUserName = rs.getString("username");
String myPassword = rs.getString("password");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

c = DriverManager.getConnection(myURL, myUserName, myPassword);
```

### Update 1

If you need `JTextField` use below.

```
String myUserName = myUserNameTextField.getText();
String myPassword = myPasswordTextField.getText();
String myURL = "jdbc:mysql:// " + myIPTextField.getText() + ":" + myPortTextField.getText() + "/DBName"

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

c = DriverManager.getConnection(myURL, myUserName, myPassword);
```

### Good Luck!!!

Comment: OK Thanks I get it. But I want to change the values in Strings by entering into a JRAME or something like that. I can't edit the class every time. Basically, I have developed a SWING application. So I want a JRAME which has JTexfields, which will change the values of the DB Class I have created above on a button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be what you want :

```
String host = textFieldHost.getText();
String port = textFieldPort.getText();

DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/DBName",host,port), "root", "123");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this settings into .properties or XML file, and then read it when needed.

This link should Help

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use some string concatenation

```
String host = ...
int port = ...
String jdbcurl = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/DBName";
DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcurl,"root","123");
```

Comment: Cant I store the host and port in mySQL database, and retrieve it using a resultset?

Comment: And how do you first access the database when you want to first retrieve host and port from there?

Comment: Yes you are right! I cannot access the database when my IP and HOST are changed.